# Splunk: Trying to split multiline event at search time

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

```
2018-06-20T00:04:35.000+00:00 (980) WAL Autocheckpointing, name=C:\Program 
Files\PriceService\data\documents.db
2018-06-20T00:07:16.000+00:00 (980) WAL Autocheckpointing, name=C:\Program 
Files\PriceService\data\store-promotions.db
2018-06-20T00:07:21.000+00:00 (980) WAL Autocheckpointing, name=C:\Program 
Files\PriceService\data\store-promotions.db
2018-06-20T00:07:26.000+00:00 (980) WAL Autocheckpointing, name=C:\Program 
Files\PriceService\data\store-promotions.db
```

I have been trying to get my splunk query right in order to split this one event into multiple events but for some reason I cannot get my query right.

I tried to split on newline but the result set comes back unchanged. I understand from reading online I'm supposed to use something on the lines of

```
myQuery | rex field=_raw "\[(?P<field1>...).*[\r\n]"
```

Apologies by the way. My regex game is not strong.

Comment: Why do you try to match `[` if your data does not contain it? Also, why not then just use `rex field=_raw ".+"`? `.+` matches any 1+ chars other than newline.

Comment: i was trying to piece together examples that i've seen online but regex is almost alien to me.

Comment: .*[\r\n] seems to be just what i need when testing the regex in sublime text editor. Its only when i hook it into the rest of my splunk query do i get no joy. I just get back the same event with the above multiple entries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realise that this could simply be done using

```
myQuery | multikv noheader=t
```

I hope this helps someone else as I spent a couple hours trying to get the regex right.

EDIT: Fixed command.

Answer (score 3):

Try `... | eval events=split(_raw, "\n") | mvexpand events | ...`.

BTW, regex101.com is great for testing regex strings.